# Fetching data in an AJAX-page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my AJAX-page I want to fetch data from a database. In my first page I have `del image` to delete a record. I passed the file cid as 'rmvfile' to the next page and fetched and displayed them on the 2nd page.

In my first page I pass cf_id:

```
<img src="image/delete1.png" alt="delete" style="width:10px;height:10px" title="Remove" onclick="myFunction('.$fet['cf_id'].');">

function myFunction(cid) {   
    var rmvfile=cid;
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete the file?") == true) {
        if(cid!='') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'delete_cli_file.php',
                data: {rmvfile: rmvfile},
             });
        }
    }
}
```

I my 2nd page I use:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$s = $_POST['rmvfile'];
$sel = "select cf_id from client_file where cf_id='".$_POST['rmvfile']."'";
$sel1 = mysql_query($sel);

$sfet = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel1);
$file_name = $sfet['file_name'];  //not fetched
$echeck = "delete from client_file where cf_id='".$_POST['rmvfile']."'";
$echk = mysql_query($echeck);
$del = "delete from client_file where file_name = '$file_name' ";
$del1 = mysql_query($del);
?>
```

`$echeck = "delete from client_file where cf_id = '".$_POST['rmvfile']."'";` 
and `$sel="select cf_id from client_file where cf_id='".$_POST['rmvfile']."'";`  are working.

My problem is that the value is not fetched in `$sfet['file_name']`.

Comment: Your if($sel1=mysql_query($sel)){ is wrong just use if(mysql_query($sel)){

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` and see you are getting those data.

Comment: put ini_set('display_errors',1) and check for errors. tell us what error are you getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct the sql query section in your code
currently it is

```
$sel = "select cf_id from client_file where cf_id='".$_POST['rmvfile']."'";
```

it should be

```
$sel = "select * from client_file where cf_id='".$_POST['rmvfile']."'";
```

As now it is fetching only cf_id, you didn't get the other fields.

Comment: cf_id value is passed to  next

Comment: can you check the `var_dump(mysql_error());` and `var_dump($sfet);`

Comment: I get like this string(0)"" array(1){[cf_id]=>string(2)"29"}

Comment: Please use `"select * from client_file  ..... "`  -- as of now it is fetching only cf_id, its not fetching the other fields.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$del1 = mysql_query( $del ).mysql_error();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You are not fetching file_name from mysql query
```

$sel = "select cf_id from client_file where cf_id='".$_POST['rmvfile']."'";

`Change query to fetch file_name`

$sel = "select cf_id,file_name from client_file where cf_id='".$_POST['rmvfile']."'";

Answer (score 0):

In your 2nd page

```
if($sel1=mysql_query($sel)) //Wrong verification
```

Use == rather than =

```
if($sel1==mysql_query($sel))
```

Comment: $echeck="delete from client_file where cf_id='".$_POST['rmvfile']."'";
 $echk=mysql_query($echeck); is working.no no problem in if condition

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed your image-tag properly and the quotes are not closed as well

```
<img src="image/delete1.png" alt="delete" style="width:10px;height:10px"
title="Remove" onclick="myFunction('.$fet['cf_id'].');">
```

And as stated by manikiran, check the if.condition.

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql query to this

```
 $myvar= $_POST['rmvfile'];
  $sel="select cf_id from client_file where cf_id='$myvar'";
  $sel1=mysql_query($sel);

  $sfet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sel1);
  $file_name=$sfet['file_name'];
```